# custom COOKIE on custom page

Tags: functions, actions, embed, wp-head

i have problem with create function for set cookie dynamically.

when i try in custom page i have of course header is set and i tried something like this:
in custompage.php:

```
myfunction($cookiename,$cookievalue);
```

in function.php

```
add_action("init","myfunction",10,2);
function myfunction($name,$value) {
setcookie($name,$value,time()+3600);
}
add_action("wp_head","mySEOfunction",10,2);
function mySEOfunction($name,$value) {
echo "some meta tags...".$name...
}
```

i have  `Missing argument 2 in function.php` i tried also this for SEO meta tags created dynamically but i have same problem...

any help?

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is setting a cookie on a page then why the complexity?
Check this out for a simple answer http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp

My only thought is that you are then trying to redirect them back to Wordpress and if so you may wish to check this [Setting custom cookies in Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/setting-custom-cookies-in-wordpress?rq=1)

I'd say your error "missing function 2" is coming from incorrect syntax for `time`.

Comment: 1. as i said i need to set cookie dynamically for every page or something else... and you can see that i know how to set cookie for basic html/php but i don't know how to set in wp.
2. as i said i have missing function becasause i have problem with parameters so if is syntax error i will got syntax error.. end as you can see i didn't put full code