# First page download plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm sorry, but I speak a little English.

I would like create a WordPress plugin. All page view run this plugin, but if a visitor has not been to my site yet, I would like a cookie to be generated:

```
$_COOKIE [ 'referer' ] = $_SERVER [ 'HTTP_REFERER' ];
$_COOKIE [ 'url' ] = $_SERVER [ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
```

Please help me, how to?

Comment: That's pretty much it. You'll want to check if these cookies exist already before setting / overwriting them: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/setting-custom-cookies-in-wordpress

Comment: An alternative approach is to do this in JavaScript on the page, e.g. [this plugin that captures ad referrers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gf-campaign-fields/) (I'm not sure I'd recommend everything it does though). That will still work if your pages are cached aggressively and most users don't actually get to the server.